# creating a single column in a view consisting of two other columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a view with 3 columns from different tables, two of the three are firstname & lastname, is there a way to modify my view so it only has 2 columns, one being the first column and the second being a merge between firstname and lastname, call it fullname.

Currently working in microsoft sql server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [+ (String Concatenation)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to combine text

e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW NAMES
AS
SELECT Other.OtherColumn, First.Firstname + ' ' + Surn.Lastname AS Fullname
FROM Other, First, Surn
WHERE <some match condition>
```